# Create column by repeating numbers from an array in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, calculated-columns

I have a pyspark dataframe with 30 rows and an array of 6 elements. The version of pyspark as taken from MS Fabric is 3.4.

Let's say the array is [5,4,3,4,1,0].
I need to create a column that repeats these 6 numbers 5 times. That is, it creates a column with elements [5, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0, ...] and column-bind it with initial dataframe.

The repeat function does not help because it repeats the full array as new arrays. It creates [5,4,3,4,1,0], [5,4,3,4,1,0], ...

How can I create this column?

Comment: Why not do the logic in pandas dataframe and then convert the pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe?

Comment: @user238607 conversion to pandas may not be possible for very large dataframes, so it's usually better to think of a pyspark solution

Comment: @RicS : isn't the order of array values assignment to the individual rows important. this is impossible to do in a distributed manner without joins.

Answer (score 1):

As of pyspark 2.4.0, you can use a combination of [`array_repeat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_repeat.html) and [`flatten`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.flatten.html) to obtain the desired result:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('array_repeated', F.flatten(F.array_repeat('array', 5)))
```

---

#### Example

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ([5,4,3,4,1,0], ),
], ['array'])

df = df.withColumn('array_repeated', F.flatten(F.array_repeat('array', 5)))

df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|array             |array_repeated                                                                            |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[5, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0]|[5, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0]|
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: He wants the flattened array to be binded to the 30 row dataframe in order.

Comment: Thank you Ric but I need it as a column with 30 rows. I would not mind creating a new dataframe with only this column and bind it later to the main df

Comment: Ok sorry I did not understand the question. So, since now you have a 6-item array and you have a starting dataframe of 30 rows, you want it to be repeated 5 times in order to fill a new column in the same starting dataframe?

Comment: That's right. Any ideas?

Comment: As I understood your question only after your explanation, I redirect you to @user238607's comment: in Spark, it your starting 30-row dataframe is not orderable in some way, it is impossible to determine the value that needs to be assigned to each individual row without joins.